# Rodar artisan dentro de shell script linux

Tags: laravel, linux, bash, artisan

Como faço um shell script do linux para rodar um comando artisan do laravel?

ex: `php artisan migrate`

mas criar um script para rodar esse comando

Answer (score 1):

Seria algo como isso que você precisa ?

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/php /pasta/root/projeto/artisan cache:clear
```